# Outlook add-in notification on mail

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm searching about how to put an type of notification on the email like the one from Retruster add-in do it. Right below the sender info.
Can someone explain how to reproduce this feature of Outlook?
[image: Restruster add-in]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationmessages.addAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=outlook-js-preview#addAsync_key__JSONmessage__options__callback_) to add one or more infobars to a message.

Comment: In the video from Retruster they add this infobars as soon as the user opens the email. Because this addin must have some user interection how they can do that?

Comment: The first infobar, with a message that starts with "Be careful", was not added by a JavaScript add-in based on the UI. The one below it, however, looks more like an infobar that was added by a JavaScript add-in, however, this particular one was actually added by Outlook. I could not find the video from which you obtained the screenshot. If the video link is public, can you share it so that I can have a better look to be able to assist further?

Comment: Is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7Mrb1A87Rg

Comment: Do you have an idea how can I give the same experience for my users? About the infobars of course

Comment: Thanks for the video. From the video, the first infobar, containing the warning text "Be careful", was present before the add-in's taskpane was opened. I found the add-in's manifest here : https://retruster.com/assets/manifest.xml. It only contains a taskpane control. This means that the infobar was most-likely added by a service that had access to the email. The "How it works" section on their website (https://retruster.com/setup-instructions) mentions that an email will be tagged if it found to be suspicious. I think the taskpane just provides further information. It doesn't do the tagging.

Comment: Thank you! I need to implement a similar service using AI. So I gonna do more research about it!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they just set the `MailItem.Categories` property.

Comment: This is part of the add-in or exterior service?

Comment: And also the MailItem.Categories is only availible on C# or I can do in Python to?

Comment: Are you creating JS based addin or COM/VSTO?

Comment: With javascript